# Strip punctuation in an address field in PHP

Tags: php, regex, punctuation

Hey all.  I'm having some trouble getting punctuation to be stripped out of an address field...

Basically I want to take things like:

```
1234 Apple St. N.
```

And turn it into:

```
1234 Apple St N
```

A period is really the only piece of punctuation I can envision... but I suppose I'd really want to strip EVERYTHING out.  Can somebody help me here?  Nothing i do works... argh!

Comment: Everything? You mean `$address = '';`? Sorry this stupid question, but you should make clear, what should get striped, or what should remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a preg_replace get the desired result. and `\w` is short-hand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, FYI.

```
$newAddress = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/','',$oldAddress);
```

**EDIT** Now that I think about it, you probably want `[^\w\s]` so you don't remove spaces as well.

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/PWc4f)**

Comment: @Shackrock: not any more, please see my EDIT and the demo.

Comment: The question is whether `King's Road` should become `Kings Road`.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: True, though I have never seen apostrophes in a street sign. (Though I'm sure there are always exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with php's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ? This will replace all occurences of a specified string with a replacement string (including a zero length string `""`).

Comment: Works with arrays (to replace multiple at once) too :)