# Regex to strip specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I have been using the following regex to replace all punctuation in a string:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/', '', $tweet);
```

with \w being shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_] and \s is used to ommit spaces. I learned this wisdom here: [Strip punctuation in an address field in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899398). But now, I need the regex to strip all characters except

```
a-z and A-Z
{ and }
```

So it should strip out all dots, commas, numbers etc. What is the correct regex for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z{} ]/', '', $tweet);
```

Possibly faster variant as proposed by **FakeRainBrigand** in a comment, thanks:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z{} ]+/', '', $tweet);
```

Comment: Would `/[^a-zA-Z{}]+/` be better?  That way each match-replace action is done for a sequence of illegal characters, rather than each.  (Performance)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Funny you mention this. :) I thought about this myself when posting, yet had no hard benchmarked facts at hand, hence was hesistant to claim anything. Added your variant to the answer anyway, for better exposure.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is removing all spaces to. My fault - it wasn't listed as a legal character. Could somebody expand?

Comment: @Reveller: Just add a space to the character set then. (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z{}]/i', '', $tweet);
```